# Como redirecionar url com argumento para outra pagina no Django? (UpdateView, GenericView)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Bem, estou com um dúvida muito pertinente. estou com uma classe de edição do django, e quando edito o usuário, preciso que ela chama da classe de detalhe do mesmo (DetailView), as duas classes estão funcionando, porém quando chamo a url que manda para o a DetailView, ela dá erro, o que é óbvio, visto que a detail view precisa do id do usuário via GET. Porém, como passar esse id do usuário via get pela classe UpdateView, visto que ela utiliza a success_url? segue o código da classes ditas:

UpdateView:

```
class UpdateUserView(LoginRequiredMixin, IsMaintainer ,UpdateView):
    model = User
    context_object_name = 'u'
    template_name = 'update-user.html'
    fields = ['name', 'email', 'nivel']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:detail')
```

DetailView:

```
class DetailUserView(LoginRequiredMixin, IsMaintainer ,DetailView):
    model = User
    context_object_name = 'u'
    template_name = 'profile.html'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação do Django 1.11 - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy - você pode especificar os campos da URL utilizando a variável **kwargs**.

```
success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:detail', kwargs={'id': 10})
```

Dessa forma estou preenchendo o campo **:id** da rota com o valor 10.